# Xcode Beta and Additional Components

Tags: macos, xcode, development

Short question: Will installing the additional components for Xcode 10 beta interfere in any way with the currently installed, AppStore version (9.x)?

What are this "additional components"? Are they stored separately by Xcode version, or are they shared?